# Centering a form & input

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to center my form & input horizontally but it doesn't work

I've tried using margin & padding but nothing works.

```css
body {
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
}


/* Form (outside) */
.form-inline {
    padding: 1% 0%;
}

/* Input (inside) */
.form-control {
    background-color: #353434;
    border: #3E3E3E 2px solid;
    /* Top right bottom left */

    /* Align the writing in the center*/
    text-align: center;
}


/* Search text */
.form-control::placeholder {
    color: #AEAEAE;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <!-- Search inputForm -->
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="#POST">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your CSS says to center the text within the `form-control`, and that's exactly what it does...

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: how do I increase the size and have it stay in the horizontal middle?

Answer (score 0):

To vertical center your form you can do this way

```
form{
width:fit-content;
margin:0 auto
}
```

for the vertical and horizontal center you can do by `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)`. Below is working snippet

```
form{
width:fit-content;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
}


/* Form (outside) */
.form-inline {
    padding: 1% 0%;
}

/* Input (inside) */
.form-control {
    background-color: #353434;
    border: #3E3E3E 2px solid;
    /* Top right bottom left */

    /* Align the writing in the center*/
    text-align: center;
}


/* Search text */
.form-control::placeholder {
    color: #AEAEAE;
    text-align: center;
}
form{
width:fit-content;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<header>
    <!-- Search inputForm -->
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="#POST">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), in bootstrap to center as u want the class to use is :

```
justify-content-center
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
    <!-- Search inputForm -->
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 justify-content-center" action="#POST">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: bootstrap has predefined many classes that you intend to implement, for example: in background-color: #2F2F2F in bootstrap u should use bg-dark; in text-align: center; in bootstrap u should use text-center, etc.
U should read [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) to not repeat same class or properties.

Comment: thanks a lot man, let's say I want to increase the width, should I use padding or should I use width: bla bla bla?

Comment: width of course

Comment: Okay so rn i'm trying to increase the width of the entire form but it doesnt change anything. Also when should I use padding?

Comment: i dont sure what you want to do, maybe u are asking for bootstrap column system and his responsive system

Comment: i'm not asking for a culmn systen nor a responsive system im simply asking how to increase the width of my search form since right now when I change the width it just pushes it to the side and doesnt change anything.